# Get mobile phone operator from android CallLog

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, calllog

is it possible to get the name of the mobile phone operator from the android [CallLog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html)? E.g. in Germany phone numbers have xxxx - xxxxxxx form.

Normally the first 4 numbers of the phone number are an identifier for the mobile phone operator. But in Germany you can switch the operator, porting your mobile phone number to your new operator. So the xxxx itself is no longer a hint what operator is behind a phone number or a call.

Is it possible to get such information from the CallLog or any other log of the android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Provider detection and routing is done at the [backend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_and_Switching_Subsystem) - the phone just receives the phone number in the "incoming call" event.

Comment: so we can analyse just the phone numbers to get the providers? that will work for the bigger part of the numbers but it is not be best way to do that

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: No - as you said, in many countries there is no longer a strong correlation between the number prefix and operator. The best result you can get is "that number would have been with operator X some years ago", but that's useless - it doesn't tell you anything about the current operator. I don't think operators have some sort of API to find whether a number belongs to them - I think what you're asking for is not possible.